# execute some function in some php file on another server(apache) and get the returned value

Tags: php

I want to access some function written in some php file on another server and receive the input, I have access to those server files so that I can change them for proper configuration, I have all the privilleges to do so, can anybody please guide me how can I do it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://some.server/out.php");
```

and in this out.php

```
<?php
include 'some.php';
function();
```

Comment: I think this will use the function() in that file locally, actually, the function I want to use is connected to database over that server, so basically what I want to do is, to receive the request over that server execute the required function, and send the generated response, how can I do this ??

Comment: you need to learn how PHP works, I suppose. what is HTTP server and what is HTTP call. It will clear matters for you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement web service or an api, and the output could be in xml or json read the content and use it on your website.

It is just Facebook graph API using URL
https://graph.facebook.com/Pepsi

The above link will fetch information regarding Facebook page of Pepsi.